# Do Angular routes subscribe to the observable a RouteGuards returns?

Tags: angular, typescript, angular-route-guards

I'm a little confused by how Angular routes treat the observables that a guard returns. Take the following route guard:

```
export class AuthenticationGuard implements CanActivate {

  constructor(private sessionQuery: SessionQuery, private router: Router){}

  canActivate(
    next: ActivatedRouteSnapshot,
    state: RouterStateSnapshot): Observable<boolean | UrlTree> | Promise<boolean | UrlTree> | boolean | UrlTree {

    const loginPage = this.router.parseUrl('/login')

    return this.sessionQuery.loggedIn$.pipe(
      map((loggedIn: boolean): boolean | UrlTree => {
        console.log('loggedIn emitted: ', loggedIn)
        return loggedIn ? true : loginPage
      })
    )
  }
}
```

The guard returns an observable that maps `this.sessionQuery.loggedIn$` to either `true` if the value is `true` or `loginPage` if `false`.

However, I would expect that the route guard would subscribe to the observable: `this.sessionQuery.loggedIn$` observable so that when it re-emits, the logic in the route-guard is re-evaluated.

However testing appears to show that it doesn't. If I subscribe to this observable elsewhere in the app I can see it re-emit but the `console.log` call I've put in the code above doesn't fire.

I would like the route guard to trigger an automatic logout when the `loggedIn$` observable emits `false`.

If the route isn't subscribing the the guard then what's the point in the guard returning an observable in the first place? I feel like there's something I'm missing here...

Comment: Prevent check URL on guard logic. guard specified on route definition https://angular.io/api/router/CanActivate

Comment: I'm confused about this as well, have you figured it out?

Comment: I’m not  sure on the underlying truth of this but I concluded that the most useful way to think about this was to assume that the guard subscribes to the observable, waits for the first emission and then unsubscribes. My understanding is that the subscription is only in play during the page loading process (as Clemens describes below)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You'll have to implement the logic for "route to login when `sessionQuery.loggedIn$` emits false somewhere else, maybe in a service that is eagerly injected in its parent module (to make sure it is instantiated).

To check what Angular is doing with the returned Observable, you may return the following. My guess is, that Angular gets the first emitted value and unsubsribes.

```
return new Observable<boolean | UrlTree>((subscriber) => {
    const subscription = this.sessionQuery.loggedIn$.pipe(
      map((loggedIn: boolean): boolean | UrlTree => {
        console.log('loggedIn emitted: ', loggedIn)
        return loggedIn ? true : loginPage
      })
    ).subscribe(subscriber);

    return () => {
        // called when no subscriber is left
        console.log('unsubscribed');
        subscription.unsubsribe();
    };
});
```